# How to refactor files/python modules in VScode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am able to refactor variables in VScode, but I would like to refactor the module names so that the import of those modules are automatically resolved.
A similar feature is present in JetBrains Pycharm but I could not find in VScode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename and Refactor a Python File in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70107143/rename-and-refactor-a-python-file-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

Such a feature doesn't exist in the Python extension for VS Code. To request it, open an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python .

Answer (score 0):

Update: This issue has been raised in [issue 4628](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4628). The feature still doesn't exist for now, but hopefully it will soon.