# Can VS Code automatically update Python import paths on file rename/move?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import

If I import some module from a **python** file and then I move/rename this file, is there a vscode setting that allows to update import statements automatically?

Example:

I import some file `utils.py` from `dir`.

```
import dir.utils
```

Then I move utils to `new_dir`. I want the import statement to be updated automatically:

```
import new_dir.utils
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename and Refactor a Python File in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70107143/rename-and-refactor-a-python-file-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 3):

This is of course possible, and this feature is enabled by default.

[image]

More information can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_refactoring) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring).

Comment: I don't have this feature, maybe I pressed "do not ask me again" at some point. Is there a way to re-enable it?

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76206135/19133920) helps.